# Invoke and MethodInvoke

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Hello there could anyone help me fixing this part of code:

```
If dlbar.Dispatcher.CheckAccess Then
        Dispacher.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                               dlbar.Maximum = CSm
                                           End Sub))
```

And:

```
 If dlbar.Dispatcher.CheckAccess Then
                    Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                 dlbar.Value += 1
                                                 End Sub))

                Else
```

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria is backwards:

```
If Not Dispatcher.CheckAccess Then
    Dispacher.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                                           dlbar.Maximum = CSm
                                       End Sub))
Else
    dlbar.Maximum = Csm
End If
```

`CheckAccess` returns true when you don't need to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Still showing errors Dispacher is not declared and MethodInvoker is not defined?

Comment: again Dispacher is not declared :S

Comment: @Onlykl Where is this code located?  Is it in a Window or UserControl?

Comment: want me to copy whole source?